# Fast-logger clean up action (haskell)

Tags: haskell, logging

I'm willing to use the fast-logger haskell library, but i have some questions:

Function `newTimedFastLogger` is explained as:

> Initialize a FastLogger with timestamp attached to each message. a tuple of logger and clean up action are returned.

So, first question, what is this "clean up action" for?

Also, that function takes an `IO FormattedTime` as first argument, but then we have:

`type TimedFastLogger = (FormattedTime -> LogStr) -> IO ()`

That's my second question, why do i have to supply a FormattedTime both when creating the TimedFastLogger and when using it?

Comment: You've misunderstood what the type `(A -> B) -> IO ()` means. This doesn't demand a value of type `A`; it demands a value of type `A -> B`. By supplying a function of type `A -> B` you can access a value of type `A`, but only within the scope of that function. In other words, `TimedFastLogger` supplies you with a `FormattedTime`, not the other way around.

Comment: I just really dont understand why `TimedFastLogger` is defined like that

Comment: How would you expect it to be defined? Or what do you think is wrong with the actual definition? This seems like a natural way to define it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the source for the function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fast-logger-2.4.10/docs/src/System-Log-FastLogger.html#newTimedFastLogger) you will see that the clean-up action is a call to `rmLoggerSet`. The documentation for that says:

> Flushing the buffers, closing the internal file information and freeing the buffers.

So that should answer your first question. You would run it when you don't need the logger anymore to make sure any state state associated with it is "cleaned up". It may do different things depending on the type of logger you are using.

For the second question `IO FormattedTime` is an action which can be called by the logger whenever it needs a timestamp for a log message. So it may call it multiple times and get a different `FormattedTime`. When you call `newTimedFastLogger` you pass this action as the first argument and it gives you back a logger and the clean up action. So, using it would go something like:

```
import System.Log.FastLogger
import Data.Monoid ((<>))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    timeCache <- newTimeCache simpleTimeFormat
    (logger, cleanUp) <- newTimedFastLogger timeCache (LogStdout defaultBufSize)
    log logger "Some log message"
    cleanUp

log :: ToLogStr msg => TimedFastLogger -> msg -> IO ()
log logger msg = logger $ \ft -> toLogStr ft <> toLogStr ": " <> toLogStr msg
```

Each time you log a message, you are calling `logger`, and passing in a callback that tells it how to combine your message with whatever value of the time (`ft`) it currently has. Depending on your requirements, you might want a different format, perhaps including log levels in the output.

Comment: toLogStr ft <> toLogStr ": " <> toLogStr msg == foldMap toLogStr [ft, ": ", msg]